# TileListItemRenderer in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, adobe

I followed an example to display a list and the code is as follows...

```
<mx:TileList id="tileList"
                 dataProvider="{xmlListColl}"
                 itemRenderer="TileListItemRenderer"
                 columnCount="3"
                 columnWidth="150"
                 rowCount="2"
                 rowHeight="100" />
```

The itemRenderer is:

```
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
           x="496" y="10" width="221" height="317" backgroundColor="#98AEEF">

    <mx:Image source="{data.@src}"
            horizontalCenter="0"
            verticalCenter="0" />

    <mx:Label text="{data.@lbl}"
            fontWeight="bold"
            horizontalCenter="0"
            bottom="0" />

</mx:Canvas>
```

Now I wanted help to have these images with drag enabled. All the dragDrop functions are within the main mxml file...I am a bit lost here. Any other information required please do ask me.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want drag functionality for sorting the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set dragEnabled to true on your TileList.  If you're just rearranging within the TileList, then set its dragMoveEnabled and dropEnabled to true.  If you want to drag it to another List, set dropEnabled true on that list, but if you want to copy from one list to another, see "Maintaining type information during a copy" here http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dragdrop_7.html.

If your destination is a container, check out http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dragdrop_7.html .

FWIW, I would have only needed to give you one of those pieces of information if you'd given more info about what you are trying to do. You're the one seeking help, so you should put forth at least as much effort as you're asking others to.

Comment: I am sorry about it. I did not explain it well. I want to drag and drop it into another canvas. really appreciate your help.. Will try them all and let you know.